# EJB3 case-sensitive annotations

Tags: sql-server, orm, jpa, annotations, case-sensitive

We are connecting to a SQL Server to persist our EJB3 objects. These objects are annotated up with @Column.

If the column name in the database starts with a capital letter (E.g. OrderName) will the ejb annotation have case sensitivity issues if the element is defined like such:

```
@Column
String orderName
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll face case sensitivity issues. Or maybe if you created your database with a Case Sensitive collation (in which case all object names will be Case Sensitive). But even if you did, you can always set the name of columns in your @Column annotations:

```
@Column(name="ORDeRNAME")
```